# use root path to file instead of subproject path for zipTree

Tags: gradle

I've got this project structure

```
journey\
    applications\
    desktop\
    core\
```

I've got a task that downloads `.zip` archive.

```
task download_redis(type: Download) {
    src 'https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases/download/win-3.2.100/Redis-x64-3.2.100.zip'
    dest new File("applications/redis/install", 'Redis-x64-3.2.100.zip')
    onlyIfNewer true
}
```

It saves `zip` file into `applications\redis\install`. 
Then I've got another task that supposed to extract the content of `zip` file into `applications/redis`.

```
task install_redis(dependsOn: download_redis, type: Copy) {
    from zipTree(download_redis.dest) 
    into 'applications/redis'
}
```

But I get this error

```
Cannot expand ZIP 'L:\journey\desktop\applications\redis\install\Redis-x64-3.2.100.zip' as it does not exist.
```

It seems trying to resolve the path to `zip` from `desktop` project, despite it being level higher - a `root`.

How to set for `zipTree` to use path from `root` and not from subproject? (Though both these tasks are inside `desktop` subproject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access various paths like so:

```
println project(":applications").projectDir
println project(":desktop").projectDir
// root
println project(":").projectDir
```

Here is an example `:desktop:build.gradle` file that uses a spoof zip download. Note the `applicationsDir` variable. (I'm assuming that you are using the same plugin as the one specified.):

```
plugins {
    id "de.undercouch.download" version "1.2"
}

apply plugin: 'de.undercouch.download'

import de.undercouch.gradle.tasks.download.Download

def applicationsDir = project(":applications").projectDir

task download_redis(type: Download) {
    src 'https://github.com/codetojoy/Git_Sandbox/raw/master/tmp/example.zip'
    dest new File("${applicationsDir}/redis/install", 'Redis-x64-3.2.100.zip')
    onlyIfNewer true
}

task install_redis(dependsOn: download_redis, type: Copy) {
    from zipTree(download_redis.dest) 
    into "${applicationsDir}/redis"
}
```